# Retrieve distinct values from datatable using linq vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I am trying to retrieve all of the distinct values from a particular column in a datatable.  The column name in the datatable is "Count".  I have 2240 rows and I have 6 distinct values in the "Count" column.  The problem is, when I execute the following code, it is giving me the number of rows rather than the 6 distinct values.

```
Dim counts = (From row In loadedData
Select row.Item("Count")).Distinct()
For Each i In counts
    MsgBox(i)
Next
```

How can I modify this to retrieve the 6 distinct values, rather than it giving me the total number of rows?

Comment: FYI - The values in this datatable are all unique... except that of the "Count" column.  I believe this is why it is returning the 2240 rows, instead of just the 6 unique count values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to select the column and use `Enumerable.Distinct`:

```
Dim distinctCounts As IEnumerable(Of Int32) = loadedData.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("Count")).
    Distinct()
```

In query syntax(i didn't know that even `Distinct` is supported directly in VB.NET):

```
distinctCounts = From row In loadedData
                 Select row.Field(Of Int32)("Count")
                 Distinct
```

Comment: I tried to use your code you posted, but I don't think you read my last comment. All 2240 are unique, however I am just trying to get the unique count column.  "Select distinct count from datatable" - essentially.

Comment: @JohnJanssen: That is exactly the `Linq-To-DataSet` equivalent from your posted sql query. It returns only the distinct counts from the table. So if the table contains 2240 rows and the `Count` column contains 6 different numbers(spread over all rows), the query returns only 6 different numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ToTable(distinct As Boolean, ParamArray columnNames As String()) method for this.

```
loadedData.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "Count")
```

This will return distinct Users for you. You can add multiple column names if you want.

Here is the msdn documentation.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

you can also apply this logic if you want ,
first sort datatable through columName ,
then apply this logic

```
    dtRecords.DefaultView.Sort = "columnName"
    dtRecords = dtRecords.DefaultView.ToTable
    Dim totalRecords As Integer = 0
    Dim thNameStr As String = filter(dtRecords, "columnName", totalRecords )

Public Shared Function filter(ByVal dtRecords As DataTable, ByVal columnName As String, ByRef totalRecords As Integer) As String
            Dim FilterStr As String = ""
            Dim eachTotal As Integer = 0
            totalRecords = 0
            Dim lastName As String = ""
            For rCount = 0 To dtRecords.Rows.Count - 1
                If lastName <> "" And lastName <> dtRecords.Rows(rCount)("" & columnName) Then
                    FilterStr &= lastName & " - [" & eachTotal & "]"
                    eachTotal = 0
                    totalRecords += 1
                End If
                lastName = dtRecords.Rows(rCount)("" & columnName)
                eachTotal += 1
            Next
            FilterStr &= lastName & " - [" & eachTotal & "]"
            totalRecords += 1
            Return FilterStr 
        End Function
```

Comment: A little bloated. That just seems like a lot of code to do the same thing that I can do in 3 lines of code with LINQ. The code doesn't seem wrong at all though.