# Linq to create dictionary to add only unique items

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I am using below code to create a dictionary, however, there are some duplicate due to which it gives the exception

> Item with the same key has already been added.

I am not sure how can I modify the below statement to add only unique items.

```
If TempDT IsNot Nothing Then 
    m_ConcurrentScriptDictionary = TempDT.AsEnumerable.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.SafeField(fldClusterId, NULL_ID_VALUE), Function(y) y.SafeField(fldParamValue11, NULL_ID_VALUE))    
End If
```

Can you please help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247504/retrieve-distinct-values-from-datatable-using-linq-vb-net

Comment: are they direct duplicates or just the keys the same? you can filter the enumerable before you ToDictionary with distinct if they are duplicates or group by and take one if they are not.

Comment: I have tried using Distinct, but it does not work. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong as I am not quite familiar in linq. Can you show me how to apply group by or distinct on my linq?

Comment: @LewisTaylor Keys are same.